# Installing PyGraphics-1.5.win32.exe

Tags: python-2.6

When I try to install PyGraphics-1.5.win32.exe it pops up with an error stating:

"The program can't start because MSVCR71.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem."

I have tried reinstalling Python and have had no luck. My installation currently includes PyWin, Pyserial, and PIL on Windows 7 x64.

Any help much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could Google for the missing DLL, and copy it into the Python installation directory.
But it's probably easier to just grab the [Visual Studio 2005 SP1 Redistributable (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=200b2fd9-ae1a-4a14-984d-389c36f85647&displaylang=en) runtime package from Microsoft. I think you'll need the x86 version of the runtime (rather than x64), since PyGraphics-win32 sounds like a 32-bit library, not 64-bit.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, need this for a project due in 10 hours and barely have any work done on it so far :).